# How to move Array up another level by key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have an array like below and what I want to achieve is basically remove the keys like @attributes and AddressSop and make them all one level so it removes the parent keys and array but keeps the key value pairs:

```
[Addresses] => Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [AddrCountry] => US
            [AddrLine1] => Test Street
            [AddrLine2] => Test
            [AddrLine3] => Test
            [AddrName] => Mr John Doe
            [AddrEmail] => test@test.com
            [AddrMasterPriceBook] => 
            [AddrMobile] => 123132142242
        )
    [1] => Array
      (
       ...
      )
)
```

This is how the original array looks. Any help will be awesome thank you.

```
[Addresses] => Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
        [@attributes] => Array
            (
                [AddrCountry] => US
                [AddrLine1] => Test Street
                [AddrLine2] => Test
                [AddrLine3] => Test
                [AddrName] => Mr John Doe
            )

        [AddressSOP] => Array
            (
                [@attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [AddrEmail] => test@test.com
                        [AddrMasterPriceBook] => 
                        [AddrMobile] => 123132142242
                    )

            )
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [@attributes] => Array
            (
                [AddrCountry] => US
                [AddrLine1] => Test Street
                [AddrLine2] => Test
                [AddrLine3] => Test
                [AddrName] => Mr John Doe
            )

        [AddressSOP] => Array
            (
                [@attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [AddrEmail] => test@test.com
                        [AddrMasterPriceBook] => 
                        [AddrMobile] => 123132142242
                    )

            )
    )
)
```

Comment: I tired this but removes some keys because they are duplicates:  function filterArray(array $array) {
    $values = [];
    foreach($array as $key => $level) {
        if (is_array($level)) {
            $values = array_merge($values, filterArray($level));
        } else {
            $values[$key] = $level;
        }
    }
    return $values;
}

Comment: You're better off amending your question, as others will want to know as well. Plus, multi-line code is hard to read in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach ($addresses as $key => $address) {
    $addresses[$key] = array_merge($address['@attributes'], $address['AddressSOP']);
}
```

If you want it to be recursive, you can do something like this:

```
$filtered = [];

foreach ($addresses as $addressKey => $address) {
    array_walk_recursive($address, function($val, $key) use(&$filtered, $addressKey) {
        $filtered[$addressKey][$key] = $val;
    });
}

print_r($filtered);
```